# Entering data into multiple form inputs in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to fill out a form in Puppeteer with an email and password, and then hit submit.

Each time the tests are run either the email or password isn't fully entered before the submit button is pressed. This is a cut-down version of what I'm doing:

```
await page.type(selectorSlackInputEmail, email);
await page.type(selectorSlackInputPassword, password);
await page.click(selectorSlackButtonSignIn);
```

I think it might be because the test isn't properly awaiting the completion of `page.type` and therefore focus switches to the next input or the submit button is pressed before each input field is complete.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your `await` directives to cover the issue you're seeing - my best guess is that because the `type` method simply...

> sends `keydown`, `keypress`/`input` and `keyup` events [[1]](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frametypeselector-text-options)

... that maybe some listeners are taking a little while to execute their hooked functions between the sending of those events and the calling of the `click` method.

How about a workaround that explicitly checks that those selectors have the expected data before clicking submit?

```
await page.type(selectorSlackInputEmail, email);
await page.type(selectorSlackInputPassword, password);

await page.waitFor(() => {
    return document.querySelector(selectorSlackInputEmail).value = email) &&
      document.querySelector(selectorSlackInputPassword).value = password);
});

// And only *then*
await page.click(selectorSlackButtonSignIn);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists. I also tried breaking out your example so that it waited for the email to match before trying to do the password, but the same problem happens e.g. `await page.type(emailSelector, email); await page.waitFor(() => { return document.querySelector(emailSelector).value === email; });`

Comment: Thanks for trying, Tom. If you think my answer led you down the path to you preferred answer, would you mind giving an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

After trying other methods (including `await page.type` and `await page.focus` followed by `await page.keyboard.type`) this is the only thing that works for me to fill multiple form fields:

```
await signInPage.evaluate(
  (email, password) => {
    document.querySelector('input#email').value = email;
    document.querySelector('input#password').value = password;
  },
  email,
  password
);
```

This doesn't satisfy my original use case though. I want to properly simulate a user typing into forms but this method circumvents that and directly inserts values into the fields.

I'd welcome a 'proper' solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my code and decided to just use a delay with the click function.

```
await page.click('input[value="SUBMIT"]', {delay: 100});
```